# BOX: How to download file using file url?

Tags: box-api, box

I want to use Box SDK to download a file. I have the file link available in local variable

```
 var url = https://mycompany.box.com/s/c565vhytyhx5s85vjg03bgtr0h47d6nh
```

Currently `BoxClient.FilesManager.DownloadStreamAsync(fileid)` takes fileid as parameter.

How do I use url to download a file from box using Box SDK?

Comment: Does the URL you've posted require you to log into Box before downloading the file?

Comment: @JohnHoerr i found the answer after looking at the returned data from the url. Its actually box's shared url. The url returns whole html document with actual file as an image inside the html document. I used `<iframe> and sets the `src` property of iframe to this url.

Answer (score 0):

Use following Code to Download File From Box using box api

```
 BoxFile file=new BoxFile(api, fileID);
 FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file path);
 URL DownloadUrl=file.getDownloadURL();
 BufferedInputStream input=new BufferedInputStream(DownloadUrl.openStream());
```

and write above file "input" to FileOutputStream with file path where u want